# How do I query in a model the results of a CTE located in a macro?

Tags: model, macros, common-table-expression, dbt

I have been trying to create a macro that has a CTE in it. In the model that calls that macro, I need to query those results more in order to trim / cast some columns differently. I cannot do that in the macro as the macro will be used for tables with different columns. However, I get an error when trying to do that.

**My macro looks like this:
**

```
{% macro my_macro(target_table, source_name) %}

with changes as (

    ....


select *
from union_of_changes

{% endmacro %}
```

**And my model calls and queries it like this
**

```
{% set result = my_macro(current_table, full_source) %}

    with results as (
        select *
        from {{ result }}
    ),

    final as (

        select
            object_id,
            buy_date::date as buy_date,
            trim(country_code) as country_code
            * except(
                object_id,
                buy_date,
                country_code
            )
        from results

    )

    select *
    from final
```

But this gives me a parse_syntax_error, probably due to having two CTEs. I was wondering what would be the best way to deal with this? Should I create an intermediate model that calls the macro? Or is there a more simple way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would just check the compiled sql, there's probably an error somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just missing parentheses around your Jinja tag.

```
select *
from ({{ result }})
```